# Ubuntu Skype

Tags: ubuntu, skype

Не работает skype в ubuntu 11.10. Сразу после соединения вылетает. Удаление xml-файла не помогает. Если у кого-то есть какое-то решение, поделитесь.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопрос не имеет никакого отношения к программированию и системному администрированию.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно не находит нужные библитотеки. Попробуйте проследить за процессом запуска. Делается это так:

```
$ sudo apt-get install strace
$ sudo strace -f -e trace=open -o run.log /путь/к/skype
```